# Use the composite Simpson's rule to approximate how far a tricycle traveled from a table with the time and velocity

Tags: numerical-methods, solution-verification, numerical-calculus, simpsons-rule

> Use the composite Simpson's rule to find how far the car traveled
> between 15:00 and 15:40 from the following table (Hora/s = Hour/s)

[image]

I did

$$I(f)\approx \frac{(b-a)}{3N}[f_0+4f_1+2f_2+4f_3+f_4] \\ =
\frac{(b-a)}{3*5}[24.2+4*35+2*41.3+4*42.8+34.8] = \\
(b-a)[30.18667]$$

$$(40)*30.18667 = 1207.45Km$$

That result is ridiculous, obviously, considering this is a tricycle. What went wrong?

Comment: It's $\frac{2}{3}$ of an hour, not $40$ hours! :)

Comment: Anyhow, $n = 4$.

Comment: @JoshuaWang oh lol. That was silly

Comment: @JoshuaWang how is n=4 if I have 5 points?

Comment: $N$ is the number of gaps between points. This makes sense if you consider $\frac{b-a}{3N} = \frac{\Delta x}{3}$.

Comment: @JoshuaWang Is the solution 25.156 Km?

Comment: @Segmentationfault The solution is not 25.156 because you have a small typo in the last velocity value: You have used 34.8 instead of 34.2

Comment: How much is $15:40-15:00$ ? In which unit ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust 40 minutes, or 2/3 of an hour

Comment: You got it now ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use hours as the time unit, your data points are:
$$
\left\{(0, 24.2),(\frac 16, 35), (\frac 13 , 41.3),(\frac 12, 42.8), (\frac 23, 34.2) \right\}
$$

The composite Simpson rule for $s = \int_0^{\frac 23} v(t) dt$ is

$$
\frac{1/6}{3}\left(24.2 + 4 \times 35 + 2 \times 41.3 + 4 \times 42.8 + 34.2 \right) = 25.1222 \,\textrm{Km}
$$

if you have any information on the smoothness of $v(t)$, namely about its forth derivative, you can derive an error bound.